# Change Class= of a <input using the ID as reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this input

```
<input type="text" class="form" name="_user_phone" id="_user_phone">
```

I need to change the class to class="form phone" or class="phone" using a script since I cant edit the code directly, I m down to anything, JS, JQuery or any other solutions, I saw some Javascript options, but haven't got it to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: _"but haven't got it to work"_ Please show us what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

try

$("#_user_phone").attr('class', 'newClass');

Answer (score 0):

This vanilla js, no library required.

```js
document.getElementById("_user_phone").className = "phone";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setAttribute();` with pure javascript
Here is an example:

```
document.getElementById('_user_phone').setAttribute("class", "phone"); //Change it!
```

Or:

```
document.getElementById('_user_phone').className = "phone"; //Change it!
```

Or use `attr()` in jQuery:

```
$("#_user_phone").attr("class", "phone"); //Change it!
```

To add two classes in jQuery, use `addClass()`:

```
$("#_user_phone").addClass("form phone"); //Change it!
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let input = document.getElementById('_user_phone');
input.classList.add('phone');

console.log(input)
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form" name="_user_phone" id="_user_phone">
```